# SQL Server queries beyond a certain character length are timing out

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, unixodbc

Recently I migrated an ETL platform from Python 2.7 to 3 and also updated its Docker image from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.

After the migration I started encountering some really strange behavior when trying to reflect SQL Server tables using SQLAlchemy with the pyodbc driver.

Initially, I was seeing this error message:

`[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Read from the server failed (20004) (SQLExecDirectW)`

I had updated SQLAlchemy from 0.9.8 to 1.3.10 (I hadn't touched pyodbc which was at 3.0.10) so I followed the advice in the documentation and changed the pyodbc driver from FreeTDS 7.0 to Microsoft ODBC Driver 17. All that did was change the error message to this:

`[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x274C (10060) (SQLExecDirectW)`

I confirmed that I could login to the server using isql and so I tried to directly run the query that SQLAlchemy is trying to run to get the table info

```sql
SELECT 
[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[TABLE_SCHEMA]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[TABLE_NAME]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[COLUMN_NAME]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[IS_NULLABLE]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[DATA_TYPE]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[ORDINAL_POSITION]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[NUMERIC_PRECISION]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[NUMERIC_SCALE]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[COLUMN_DEFAULT]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[COLLATION_NAME] 
FROM 
[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
WHERE 
[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[TABLE_NAME] = CAST(<table name> AS NVARCHAR(max)) 
AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = CAST(<schema name> AS NVARCHAR(max)) 
ORDER BY [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[ORDINAL_POSITION];
```

When I run this query the connection just hangs and eventually times out. I started playing around with the query and discovered that I can run queries just fine as long as they are under a certain character limit. For example:

```sql
-- This works (and returns all columns)
SELECT
*
FROM 
[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
WHERE 
[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[TABLE_NAME] = CAST(<table name> AS NVARCHAR(max)) 
AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = CAST(<schema name> AS NVARCHAR(max)) 
ORDER BY [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[ORDINAL_POSITION];

-- This also works
SELECT 
[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[TABLE_SCHEMA]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[TABLE_NAME]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[COLUMN_NAME]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[IS_NULLABLE]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[DATA_TYPE]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[ORDINAL_POSITION]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH]
FROM 
[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
WHERE 
[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[TABLE_NAME] = CAST(<table name> AS NVARCHAR(max)) 
AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = CAST(<schema name> AS NVARCHAR(max)) 
ORDER BY [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[ORDINAL_POSITION];

-- This causes the connection to hang after adding the line
-- , [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[NUMERIC_PRECISION]
SELECT 
[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[TABLE_SCHEMA]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[TABLE_NAME]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[COLUMN_NAME]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[IS_NULLABLE]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[DATA_TYPE]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[ORDINAL_POSITION]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH]
, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[NUMERIC_PRECISION]
FROM 
[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
WHERE 
[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[TABLE_NAME] = CAST(<table name> AS NVARCHAR(max)) 
AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = CAST(<schema name> AS NVARCHAR(max)) 
ORDER BY [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS].[ORDINAL_POSITION];
```

I am at a complete loss as to what is going on. Trying to run the reflection from an old Docker image on Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7 works fine; I can also run the query just fine if I connect to the database via DataGrip. I've tried using pymssql and that gives the first error. Is there some package/dependency that I should be checking that could cause this? When I was using the FreeTDS driver the connection string had UseNTLMv2=true and I'm not using TrustedConnection=Yes with the Microsoft driver because it wants me to set up Kerberos and I don't want to go down that rabbit hole if it's something else, considering the FreeTDS driver has the same issue.

Is this some weird network thing? Have I angered the SQL gods with my hubris? Is there any additional info I need to add?

Comment: This is an issue I've met a few times. Unfortunately, SQL Server ***still*** doesn't support Ubuntu 18.04; so upgrading *tends* to break it. I *believe* rolling back a couple of CUs fixes the issue; if you're using 2017.

Comment: Slight detour....I notice you are returning the schema while using INFORMATION_SCHEMA views. This is documented to be unreliable. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 You should instead query sys.objects, sys.columns and sys.schemas

Comment: @SeanLange, the problem is I don't have control over that query. That's coming from this part of the mssql dialect in SQLAlchemy https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/base.py#L2585-L2599

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue on Xubuntu 18.04 using current versions of SQLAlchemy (1.3.12), pyodbc (4.0.28), and ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server. Are you really still using pyodbc 3.0.10? (It's over 4.5 years old.)

Comment: @GordThompson I've tried this with both 3.0.10 and 4.0.27 and have the same issue. I should also clarify that the SQL Server instance is running on Windows, I'm just connecting over ODBC from Ubuntu.

Comment: @user2864740 it works when I revert the stack to the earlier image running on 2.7 and 16.04. Could it be something to do with the relevant dependencies that are used and the versions that get installed with their respective Ubuntu versions? The dependencies are `freetds-dev unixodbc tdsodbc unixodbc-dev`

Comment: For my test I was also connecting from an Xubuntu 18.04 client to a SQL Server instance running on Windows.