# SQLAlchemy hangs during insert while querying [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have a Python process that uses SQLAlchemy to insert some data into a MS SQL Server DB. When the Python process runs it hangs during the insert. I turned on SQLAlchemy logging to get some more information. I found that it hangs at this point where SQLAlchemy seems to be requesting table schema info about the entire DB:

```
2020-10-30 08:12:07 [11444:6368] sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine._execute_context(base.py:1235) INFO: SELECT [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME] 
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] 
WHERE [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) ORDER BY [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME]
2020-10-30 08:12:07 [11444:6368] sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine._execute_context(base.py:1240) INFO: ('dbo', 'BASE TABLE')
```

I have other "stuff" going on in the DB at this time, including some open transactions and my guess is that for whatever reason querying `[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]` creates some deadlock or blocks somehow.

I've also read ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976499/deadlock-when-querying-information-schema)) that `[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]` is a view that cannot cause a deadlock which would contradict my guess of what is causing this issue.

My question is: Can I alter the configuration/settings of SQLAlchemy so that it does not make this query in the first place?

**UPDATE 1**:
The Python code for the insert is like this:

```
with sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params).connect() as connection:
    # df is a Pandas DataFrame
    df.to_sql(name=my_table, con=connection, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Note that the code works without any problems when I run the Python script during other times of the day when I don't have those other DB transactions going on. In those cases, the log continues immediately like this, listing all the tables in the DB:

```
2020-10-30 08:13:03 [11444:6368] sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine._execute_context(base.py:1235) INFO: SELECT [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME] 
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] 
WHERE [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) ORDER BY [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME]
2020-10-30 08:13:03 [11444:6368] sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine._execute_context(base.py:1240) INFO: ('dbo', 'BASE TABLE')
2020-10-30 08:13:03 [11444:6368] sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine._init_metadata(result.py:810) DEBUG: Col ('TABLE_NAME',)
2020-10-30 08:13:03 [11444:6368] sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.process_rows(result.py:1260) DEBUG: Row ('t_table1',)
2020-10-30 08:13:03 [11444:6368] sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.process_rows(result.py:1260) DEBUG: Row ('t_table2',)
...
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Apparently when a table or other object is created in an open transaction and not committed yet, querying `[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]` will get blocked ([source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9716ce82-b281-4e43-b7d3-b6908c62d248/select-from-informationschematables-where-tabletype-view?forum=sqldatabaseengine)). Is anyone familiar with the internals of SQLAlchemy to suggest how to prevent it from making this query in the first place?

**UPDATE 3**: After posting this issue on the SQLAlchemy github ([issue link)](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5679) the SQLAlchemy devs confirmed that the query of [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] is in fact being caused by the Pandas [function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) `to_sql()`.

So, my new question is does anyone know how to disable this behavior in the Pandas `to_sql()` function? I looked over the documentation and could not find anything that would seem to help.

Comment: Possibly related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/164429/21390

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59636271/sql-server-queries-beyond-a-certain-character-length-are-timing-out

Comment: Discussed on GitHub [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5679).

Comment: @GordThompson the SQLAlchemy dev mentions using either `ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON` or `ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON` to not lock as aggressively by turning on snapshot isolation. I'm concerned about making these changes on the database level. Do you know of a setting in SQL server to make queries on `[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]` not block when an open transaction exists that has created a new table in that database?

Comment: You could try `create_engine(connection_uri, isolation_level="READ_UNCOMMITTED")` and see if that prevents the hang.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not prevent the query from hanging.

Comment: Hmm, it works for me. (Hangs without `isolation_level` and does not hang when I add it.) Perhaps try `engine = create_engine(connection_uri)` and the omit the `with` block and call `to_sql` with `engine` as the second parameter. That works for me, too.

Comment: That is strange, it doesn't work for me. Also just tried engine = ... as you suggested and it also did not work. The code hangs on `table_names = [r[0] for r in connection.execute(s)]` in `get_table_names` of `sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.base.py`. Just to be clear, when you test this, you have an open transaction on the same database where you have created a new table in that database in the open transaction? That's what I have and as soon as I rollback or commit that transaction in SQL the Python code continues running again.

Comment: @Joe - *"Just to be clear, when you test this, you have an open transaction on the same database where you have created a new table in that database in the open transaction?"* - Yes, exactly.

Comment: Darn. Still doesn't work for me. Perhaps their are some database related settings that are causing the difference. I wonder if their is some way I can confirm the `isolation_level="READ_UNCOMMITTED"` option is being used in general.

Comment: `SELECT transaction_isolation_level FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @@SPID;` returns the numeric value. `1` means READ_UNCOMMITTED.

Comment: Anyone ever figure out a fix for this? We've been stuck for a couple of days because of this.

Comment: I have not...just ended up monkey patching Pandas for the time being.

Comment: Encountered this too while a separate process is creating a large columnstore index. It locks information_schema and prevents to_sql from running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of pandas v.2.2.0 you can override the pandas method that runs the check which causes the block/deadlock. Add this before calling `to_sql`:

```
from pandas.io.sql import SQLDatabase
def pass_check_case_sensitive(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
SQLDatabase.check_case_sensitive = pass_check_case_sensitive
```

Comment: Good workaround - this should also work in v1.3+, right?
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1.3.x/pandas/io/sql.py

Comment: @Gabe Yes, should work there as well. FWIW none of the other workarounds were options for more or worked for me which is why I posted this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with SQLAlchemy, but I can tell you about the Pandas side of this issue.

Pandas automatically creates a new table if the table doesn't exist. The way it figures out whether the table exists is that it calls `has_table()` in SQL Alchemy. The way `has_table()` works is that it queries the information schema. (At least, it works that way in MySQL and MSSQL.)

#### Implementation details

Here's what I found tracing the logic for this in Pandas and SQLAlchemy. We start in pandas/io/sql.py, inside `to_sql()`.

```py
        table = SQLTable(
            name,
            self,
            frame=frame,
            index=index,
            if_exists=if_exists,
            index_label=index_label,
            schema=schema,
            dtype=dtype,
        )
        table.create()
```

SQLTable.create() is defined here:

```py
class SQLTable(PandasObject):
    [...]
    def create(self):
        if self.exists():
            if self.if_exists == "fail":
                raise ValueError(f"Table '{self.name}' already exists.")
            elif self.if_exists == "replace":
                self.pd_sql.drop_table(self.name, self.schema)
                self._execute_create()
            elif self.if_exists == "append":
                pass
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"'{self.if_exists}' is not valid for if_exists")
        else:
            self._execute_create()
```

Notice that it calls `exists()` unconditionally. Inside `SQLTable.exists()`, you'll find this:

```
    def exists(self):
        return self.pd_sql.has_table(self.name, self.schema)
```

This eventually calls `has_table()` in SQLAlchemy:  https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/internals.html#sqlalchemy.engine.default.DefaultDialect.has_table

For MSSQL, this is implemented in sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/base.py in SQLAlchemy:

```py
    @_db_plus_owner
    def has_table(self, connection, tablename, dbname, owner, schema):
        if tablename.startswith("#"):  # temporary table
            [...]
        else:
            tables = ischema.tables

            s = sql.select(tables.c.table_name).where(
                sql.and_(
                    tables.c.table_type == "BASE TABLE",
                    tables.c.table_name == tablename,
                )
            )

            if owner:
                s = s.where(tables.c.table_schema == owner)

            c = connection.execute(s)

            return c.first() is not None
```

(`ischema` is an abbreviation of information_schema, and this code is running a select on that table.)

#### How to fix this

I don't see a good, simple way to fix this. Pandas assumes that `has_table()` is a cheap operation. MSSQL doesn't follow that assumption. No matter what `if_exists` is set to, Pandas will call `has_table()` during `to_sql()`.

I can think of a hacky way of doing this, though. If you were to [monkey-patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545982/monkey-patching-a-class-in-another-module-in-python) `pandas.io.sql.SQLTable.create()` so that it's a no-op, then you could trick Pandas into thinking that the table already exists. The downside of this is that Pandas won't automatically create tables.

Comment: I think you are basically on the right track, but the issue occurs after the insert. When Pandas to_sql does a check on whether the table might have case sensitivity issues (look for: `# check for potentially case sensitivity issues (GH7815)` in to_sql) it ends up calling the function `get_table_names` in SQLAlchemy which is ultimately what causes the block.

Comment: one relevant (albeit closed) github issue here: 
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/36542

Comment: also here: 
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/52601

Comment: A simple workaround is to break the transactions into two statements: 1) a small initial insert that commits the table schema DDL and 2) an append of the remaining records.  Not the prettiest of solutions but it works.

Comment: @TonyDiFranco In principle, yes, but `to_sql()` doesn't give you that option. If you are doing the insert yourself then you have the freedom to do this.

Comment: @NickODell it doesn't explicitly give you this option but executing `df.iloc[:1, :].to_sql(if_exists='replace')` an then `df.iloc[1:, :].to_sql(if_exists='append')` is the workaround that I mention.  It will prevent from holding a lock on the information schema in ms sql server.

Answer (score 1):

execute set transaction isolation level read uncommitted before calling to_sql/

Answer (score 1):

I created this issue to keep track

- https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/52601

This only occurs if the table name has any uppercase letters. `MyTable` will get stuck, while `mytable` will finish successfully.

**highlighting code lines below.**

- https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7212ecd7791d92d83b7a5d48ababae6b67e4670e/pandas/io/sql.py#L1943
- - due to this PR - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/8180
- https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/b468775b5c8eb7ac17638d02fdca98b73c02bb94/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/base.py#L3348
- Note, this only gets blocked if the table name has an uppercase letter or all characters are digits.

Is this an issue that Pandas needs to correct? or SQLAchemy? I think Pandas

**Workaround**

Option 1: Use lowercase names in the table.

Option 2. set `Transaction Isolation Level` to `Read Uncommitted` in the SQLAchemy engine.

Option 3: some other user mentioned [specifying the driver version](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/36542#issuecomment-1857860983)

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mssql.html#transaction-isolation-level

```
engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params)
                          , fast_executemany=True
                           , isolation_level="READ UNCOMMITTED"
                          )
```

Answer (score 1):

Mentioning the proper version of the ODBC driver in the connection string has solved this for me. I don't know how it solved it but the error is gone.

Sample code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db_connection_str = ( 
    'mssql+pyodbc://test_user:test_password@localhost/test_database'
    '?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server&TrustServerCertificate=yes'
)
engine = create_engine(db_connection_str)

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 'name': ['John', 'Mary', 'Peter']})
df.to_sql("my_empty_table", engine,if_exists="append", index=False)
```

Comment: What is the `db_connection_str` that failed?